# Error on file type

Tags: php, file, types

Here is my code

```
if ($_FILES['foto']['size'] > 200000) die ('file too big');
if($_FILES['foto']['type'] !== "image/pjpeg" ||
$_FILES['foto']['type'] !=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES['foto']['type']
!=="image/gif")  die ('file not allowed!');
```

no matter what i upload it always showing "file not allowed". It works fine if i delete the file checking part.

I wonder where are the mistakes.

Thanks

== update===
var dump
string(10) "image/jpeg"

Comment: var dump --> string(10) "image/jpeg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a contradiction (Always False):

```
$_FILES['foto']['type'] !== "image/pjpeg" ||
$_FILES['foto']['type'] !== "image/jpeg" || 
$_FILES['foto']['type'] !== "image/gif"
```

Since for the whole statement to be true `$_FILES['foto']['type']` Must be equal to "image/pjpeg", "image/jpeg", **and** "image/gif" at the same time.

You mean to be using `&&` instead of `||`, so you get:

```
$_FILES['foto']['type'] !== "image/pjpeg" &&
$_FILES['foto']['type'] !== "image/jpeg" &&
$_FILES['foto']['type'] !== "image/gif"
```

Comment: I like my in_array more :) as it doesn't have the duplication and is a bit easier to extend by adding more mimetypes to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should log $_FILES['foto']['size'] and $_FILES['foto']['type']. That will at least let you know what is being used during your comparisons.

Comment: i echo the file type and got image/jpeg

Comment: the size is only 10KB. The size checking is working fine, the problem is only on file type checking.

Comment: Well your logic says.. if it is not A || B || C.. you need to modify that to be something using an include.

Answer (score 0):

Can't figure out how to do a multiline edit of my comment:

```
if ($_FILES['foto']['size'] > 200000) die ('file too big');
if($_FILES['foto']['type'] !== "image/pjpeg" ||
$_FILES['foto']['type'] !=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES['foto']['type']
!=="image/gif")  die ('file not allowed!');
```

Maybe try this:

```
if ($_FILES['foto']['size'] > 200000) die ('file too big');
$file_types = array("image/pjpeg", "image/jpeg", "image/"gif");
if(!in_array($_FILES['foto']['type'],$file_types)) die ('not allowed');
```